# Select a table based on select result from another table

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I have a table `Registrationrequests` where I have `course_id` and `user_id` and some other field.

```
$users_id = Registrationrequest::where('course_id', $query_course_user)->where('registered', 1)->get();
```

From the above `query` it gives me an array of result. But I need to take the details of these user_id from another table `Users`. I'm using Laravel. Table models are `Registrationrequest` and `User`

How can I get the user details from the above select result? I'm not that good in Joins. Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Eloquent's `whereHas` method:

```
$courseId = Request::get('course_id');

$users = User::whereHas('registrationRequests', function($query) use ($courseId)
{
    $query->where('course_id', $courseId)->where('registered', 1);
});
```

This assumes you have set up the proper relationship in your `User` model. If not, add this method to your user model:

```
public function registrationRequests()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Registrationrequest');
}
```

Comment: I tried this:

`$query_course_user=Request::get('course_id');
if($query_course_user!=null) {

            $users = User::whereHas('registrationrequests', function($query)
            {
                $query->where('course_id', $query_course_user)->where('registered', 1);
            });

        }`

But shows $query_course_user as undefined variable!

Comment: Error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::registrationrequests()`

This 

`registrationrequests` is another table

Comment: What you mean by `relationship's method name`? I'm just a beginner in laravel. Sorry if I sounds dumb!